# Unable to remove Nuget Package which has been deleted from the package source

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a Nuget package which I need to remove from a project, however, after restoring all of the packages in a solution, one package in a single project wouldn't remove, as it is no longer in the Package Source.

When I attempt to remove it, I would get the error of:

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '[Package Version]' of package '[Package Name]'.
>
> [Package Source Directory]: Package '[Package Name].[Package Version]' is not found on source '[Package Source Directory]'

I would also get similar errors from the Microsoft SDK and Nuget.org sorces too.

I have tried looking inside of the `app.config`, but there is no reference to the no-longer available package. The project also doesn't appear to have an `packages.config`.

I need help in removing this from the project, It appears when I right click the project and select 'Manage Nuget Packages'. When I select `Uninstall`, I would get the error above. The package also it isn't listed in the references, and I don't know where It could be referenced.

**Solved**

Turns out there *was* a `packages.config` after all. It just wasn't included in the Solution Explorer for some strange reason.

Comment: since you installed the package from npm it should be refered in packageconfig file i would say clean solution then rebuild solution and try again...and also run vs as admin(just for suraity)

Comment: Cleaned and rebuilt - No luck i'm afraid.

Comment: @SamBunting, since you have resolved this issue, you can write you solution as a answer and mark it, so it could help other community members who get the same issues, easier to find the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There are traces of the deleted package dependencies left lying around in the project (.csproj) files even after you uninstall the nuget packages. The only option then is to open the .csproj file in a text editor and manually remove the xml entries. Nuget has nothing to do with this, or I should rather say that nuget adds the assembly references in the project files during package install, but unfortunately "forgets" to remove them after the package is uninstalled.